# Корректный вызов private функции

Tags: c++, наследование

Почему следующая программа выводит `B`, ведь функция `bar` вызывает `private` функцию?

```
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "A"; }
};

struct B : A {
private:
    void foo() const override { std::cout << "B"; }
};

void bar(const A& a) { a.foo(); }


int main() {
    bar(B{});
}
```

Comment: Функция `bar` вызывает `public` виртуальную функцию `A::foo`.

Comment: @VTT тогда бы вывело `A`, а выводит `B`

Comment: То, что где-то есть класс `B`, переопределяющий функцию `foo` как `private` `B::foo`, при вызове `a.foo()` никак не учитывается. Вызов виртуальной функции никак не учитывает различные спецификаторы доступа, которые могут быть использованы в классах, переопределяющих данную виртуальную функцию. Кстати выбор для функции спецификатора доступа, отличного от того, который был в базовом классе, обычно является ошибкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это абсолютно нормальная ситуация.
[10.8.5 Access to virtual functions [class.access.virt]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.virt):

Правила доступа для виртуальных функций определяются по их объявлению и не зависят от того как функция переопределена

```
class B {
public:
  virtual int f();
};

class D : public B {
private:
  int f();
};

void f() {
  D d;
  B* pb = &d;
  D* pd = &d;

  pb->f();                      // OK: B​::​f() - public, D​::​f() вызвана
  pd->f();                      // error: D​::​f() - private
}
```

Доступность проверяется в месте вызова используя тип выражения. Какой модификатор 
доступа у переопределнной функции неизвестно.